# Facebook for developers throws 401 after logging into

Tags: spring, facebook, spring-security

I would like to connect my app with `Facebook for developers` so that't why I started doing tutorial from [link](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/). Having downloaded source code and run 'click module' everything works fine untill it goes to redirecting. When I try to log in to Facebook it throws me `401 unauthorized`.

My Facebook dashboard looks like:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your actual redirect URL really just `http://localhost:8080`?

Comment: Yes. This is exactly as described in above Spring tutorial

Comment: Well you gotta do some debugging then and find out what actually went wrong ... pretty sure the API returns an appropriate error message, and that "could not obtain access token" is just text returned by your code, but not the original error message.

Comment: Ok I do all steps again and it works..I don't know what was wrong. But I have a question. Is it possible to redirect after logging to diffrent site e.g. google.com? When I tried to put that URL into `Valid OAuth redirect URIs` I got error: `org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.UserApprovalRequiredException`

Comment: No, the redirect URIs must match your app domain(s), or the domain you used in one of the web-based platform (website, page tab, Facebook games) settings.